# How is the HOMO-LUMO gap measured?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, spectroscopy, electronic-band-theory, molecules

def:

HOMO = Highest Occupied Molecular Orbital

LUMO = Lowest Unoccupied Molecular Orbital

If the LUMO is unoccupied, how do we measure it? I can imagine that you can excite electrons in the HOMO but then the information that method will give you is the work function or ionization potential i.e. the energy required to eject an electron. It could work with fluorescence based on the emission wavelength, but what if it doesn't emit anything?

Comment: Exciting an electron into the LUMO does not mean that the molecule dissociates...

Comment: i never said the molecule dissociates? I'm essentially asking how LUMO is measured

Comment: You said that if you excite electrons in the HOMO, you will measure the energy to eject an electron. But if the electrons go into the LUMO (which they most probably will), you can measure the energy of the transition by a UV/Vis spectrophotometer.

Comment: But how do you know that they go into the LUMO?

Comment: You shine the whole spectrum onto it. The lowest energy peak will be the HOMO-LUMO transition.

Comment: I read into UV-Vis and found my answer. Apparently these LUMOs or at least excited energy states are the pi-star and sigma-star orbitals/bonds -- which are unstable electron configurations on the bonding level. I was thinking of a physics answer but in turns out the solution in the realm of molecular chemistry. Thanks a lot for your help and patience!!!